# unable to authenticate to fandromeda using scrapy

Tags: authentication, scrapy, http-post

I am new to scrapy and trying to scrape some data from [fandromeda.com](https://fandromeda.com) website but I need to authenticate first before I can start scraping the required data which is on following URL

https://fandromeda.com/v2/event/results

I am trying to use from_response method in order to try to login into the site

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from fandromeda.items import FandromedaItem

class FandromedaC(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'fandromeda_c'
    allowed_domains = ['fandromeda.com']
    start_urls = ['https://fandromeda.com/user/signin']

    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        sign_in = sel.xpath('//button[@type="submit"]/text()').extract()

        if sign_in:
            if sign_in[0] == "SIGN IN":
                self.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
                form_data = {'username': 'xxxx','password': 'xxxx' }
                return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata=form_data,callback=self.parse_login_response)

    def parse_login_response(self,response):
        self.log("#####################")
        self.log(response.status)
```

I expect to be redirected to the main page and get that content in response but all I get is login page again.

I noticed that scrapy is making get request instead of post in default case.
2016-12-01 10:53:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://fandromeda.com/user/signin?handle=&username=xxxx&password=xxxx> (referer: https://fandromeda.com/user/signin)

I tried to use method argument in from response to force scrapy to use POST method

```
scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,method="POST",formdata=form_data,callback=self.parse_login_response)
```

Now scrapy makes the post request but there is difference in the result.
Can somebody point me to the right direction on what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That website uses lots of AJAX calls to perform operations, they use AJAX to login user.

And you were using wrong URL to sign in to website.

Here is what I wrote code to sign in to that site, its 100% working code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class FandromedaCSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'fandromeda_c'
    allowed_domains = ['fandromeda.com']

    def start_requests(self):

        form_data = {"username":"mani619cash@gmail.com","password":"mani619cash@gmail.com"}
        yield FormRequest('https://fandromeda.com/user/logreg/login', callback=self.parse_login_response, formdata=form_data)

    def parse_login_response(self,response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

I also pushed the whole project into Github here https://github.com/mani619cash/fandromeda_login you can just download and run it ...

You will have to see the Firebug to see AJAX calls they are using ... for example to load user profile they send GET request via AJAX to this URL https://fandromeda.com/user/profile/info.json

See

[image]

PS:

Here is a trick ... Always disable JS in browser when you are studying the website you are trying to scrape ... because, if data is being shown in browser with JS disabled, then its 100% sure they dont use AJAX or some on-page JS to manipulate data .... and if you dont your desired data in browser after being JS disabled, then its for sure they are using AJAX or on-page JS to render/load data ... Use this to switch JS on browser https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en

Comment: Thanks a lot for the @Umair.. I will try this and let you know the results and mark this as answer. Just one more question regarding this, Is it possible for you to extend the code to make one additional call to another page such as "https://fandromeda.com/v2/event/results". Will scrapy take care of passing necessary parameters or do I have to login every time rquesting a page? Just not sure what is the right way to go with subsequent page crawls.

Comment: As I told you already that they are using too much AJAX on their site.

https://fandromeda.com/v2/event/results link also uses AJAX .... See in [screesnhot](http://imgur.com/a/ySRnX) they send AJAX to https://fandromeda.com/v2/event/result_json URL to load results data

Comment: And once you logged in using scrapy, session is created and cookies are maintained by scrapy automatically, you dont have to login before visiting each URL

Comment: Thanks I have now got idea on how to parse this site. I need to make series of GET/POST calls to various URL's to receive data and parse the JSON response. Thanks a lot again for this solution

Comment: Yeah keep your browser's inspect view (Firebug if you have Firefox) and see the AJAX calls they are using ... I am sure they only use AJAX to load all of their data on each page ... and some sites do not use AJAX, then you can use the link from browser and that will work ...

Comment: Here is a trick ... Always disable JS in browser when you are studying the website you are trying to scrape ... because, if data is being shown in browser with JS disabled, then its 100% sure they dont use AJAX or some on-page JS to manipulate data .... and if you dont your desired data in browser after being JS disabled, then its for sure they are using AJAX or on-page JS to render/load data ... Use this to switch JS on browser https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Their login page accepts a JSON not a simple form with values.

instead of doing `formdata=form_data` use `formdata=json.dumps(form_data)`

Comment: I get following error when I use this "ValueError: formdata should be a dict or iterable of tuples"

Comment: See my new answer ,,, I have created a fully working code for you